# How can I get the height of a SwiftUI List's content?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to get the height of the content of a SwiftUI List.  I am using the following that was recommended for a scrollView but it is not working:

```
.background(
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Color.clear.onAppear {
            print(proxy.size.height)
        }
    }
)
```

This just ends up giving me the height of the visible list and is always the same regardless of list contents.

Is there any way to get the content size of a List?

Comment: It is impossible to to this, because List or Form they are just a lazy view masked to all available space! They did not code to grow in height more than available space, therefore you would be unsuccessful even through background! The only way could be without List, if that you need. Or reading height of all elements of List and adding together for knowing the height of all elements! That could be also possible. But because List is lazy this method would not calculate the right value! Just do not use List if you want height.